# Webpack HotModule reloading with React Router render vs component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, webpack-hmr

I ran into an issue with HotModuleReloading, using ReactRouter for the first time.  The browser console would display the correct change updates, but the window itself would not update.

From the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. **This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.** When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

I read that as `render` reduces the amount of unnecessary re-renders, here are [their docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop receives all the same route props as the component render prop.

I had been using the `render` method like so:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

I tried removing my Redux `<Provider>` content, but no changes.  So I swapped out render for component like so and it works fine:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

So, why is this?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `component` the Route component passes certain props to the rendered component - such as `location`, `history`, `match` etc.

When you use `render` you're rendering the component in JSX like `<Home />`. This doesn't have any props passed to it.

If for whatever reason, you'd need to use `render` over `component`, you should pass the same props as `component` does:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home ...props />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

This will make sure `Home` gets the props it needs to deal with Router stuff.

Hope this helps you get to the bottom of it!